# VBA function with right function

Tags: vba, function

just wondering why the below code returns #NAME? instead of the actual value:

- The issue was due to function name

Corrected VBA function:

```
Function LocateSite_Function(Title As String) As String

Dim StartNumber As Long

StartNumber = Len(Title) - InStr(1, Title, "_")

LocateSite_Function = Right(Title, StartNumber)

End Function
```

Extra:

```
Function FindSite_Function2(Title As String) As String

Dim SplitTitle As Variant

SplitTitle = Split(Title, "_")

FindSite_Function2 = UBound(SplitTitle)

End Function
```

Comment: It works fine for me, what value of Title is causing the issue?  Also you could use split(title,"_") and then return ubound of the array produced.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but I got the value 1 instead of the value. See the code I tried in original question, Findsite_Function2

Comment: You need to ref the array at the point of ubound, so SplitTitle(UBound(SplitTitle))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess, but it is **probable that you have something else called `FindSite` in your scope**

So change the name to `FindSite_Function` and try again! ;)

Answer (score 1):

This could be the bizarre manifestation of a missing reference in your project. Have a look at your project references list (Tools -> References).

You can work around this using `VBA.Right`, or the older `Right$`.

Comment: I tried the work arounds, but I could not get it to work. What should I be looking for in the references list?